NoSuchCatalogException when using Row filter for Unity Catalog
ALTER TABLE clean.sales_dw.dim_customer SET ROW FILTER us_filter ON (region);

Throws following error:
NoSuchCatalogException: [NO_SUCH_CATALOG_EXCEPTION] Catalog 'clean' was not found. Please verify the catalog name and then retry the query or command again.
Link to the official documentation.
In the examples shown in documentation directly a tablename is used but as it is part of UC i am using the catalog.schema.table to Alter the table.
Will appreciate any help on this one.

I had the same issue and apparently the problem was not with the table's catalog, but the function's. When you define it, don't forget to use the 3-level namespace (catalog.schema.function), otherwise it will not work with Unity Catalog. Link
